# Where does Rails/ActiveRecord keep its database of plural words?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

When generating scaffolding, Rails with ActiveRecord is smart enough to pluralize "Category" to "Categories", "Man" to "Men", and so on. I doubt it is a sentient intelligence, so I figure it must keep a database of exceptions to the "add an 's' at the end" rule. Where does Rails keep that database? I mean to say, is there literally a file somewhere that I can open and examine?

Comment: Does my answer help? If so, could you mark it as the answer? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inflectors manage Rail's pluralization. An example is shown at the link below that demonstrates adding *octupus* to be `pluralized` as *octopi* :

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html

And the file exists at:

`activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb`

Link to Rail's github:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6c75a111995a9aab09e19c2b6a8a42162f689bc6/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb